# Extract a subsequence of two characters from a given string (JAVA)

Tags: java, string, substring

I am new to java programming, I was trying to come up with a method that can extract a the largest substring from a given string that is a sequence of two defined characters 
example 
consider that our two characters are B OR A
String : QWABABBBAOPAABO 
result ABABBBA
example 2 :
given string :XZAAQ
result AA

Comment: please ensure you've attempted the task at hand prior to posting.

Comment: Have you even tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
String res = ""
String current = ""
for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
    if(c == 'A' || c == 'B') {
        current += c + "";
    } else {
        if(current.length > res.length) {
            res = current;
        }
        current = "";
    }
}
if(current.length > res.length) {
    res = current;
}
```

Comment: char is not String => c == "A"

Comment: THANKS A LOT
this worked
String text="XABAAPAA";
  String res = "";
String current = "";
for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
    if(c == 'A' || c == 'B') {
        current += c + "";
    } else {
        if(current.length()> res.length()) {
            res = current;
            System.out.println(res);
        }
        current = "";
    }
}
if(current.length() > res.length()) {
    res = current;
    System.out.println(res);
}

Comment: Why are you answering a homework question with no effort shown?

Answer (score 0):

Here's using regex:

```
return str.replaceAll("[^AB]", "");
```

Comment: Thanks but it only returns all the substrings not the largest one